# Dictionary list raised a key error in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, keyerror

I have a list of dictionary, and I would like to count the values for keys of "increasing" and "decreasing" respectively. My script returned a key error that might because not all dictionaries have "increasing" and "decreasing" both. But I have no idea how to fix it. As a Python beginner, any help would be appreciated.

```
list_of_dicts = [{"decreasing": 1}, {"increasing": 4}, {"decreasing": 1}, {"increasing": 3},{"decreasing": 1},
             {"increasing": 1}]

values1 = [a_dict["decreasing"] for a_dict in list_of_dicts]
values2 = [a_dict["increasing"] for a_dict in list_of_dicts]

print(values1)
print(values2)
```

The expected result is:

```
[1,1,1]
[4,3,1]
```

Comment: Please [edit] and add the expected result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an `if` in the list comprehension, that'll keep the good ones

```
values1 = [a_dict["decreasing"] for a_dict in list_of_dicts if "decreasing" in a_dict]
values2 = [a_dict["increasing"] for a_dict in list_of_dicts if "increasing" in a_dict]

print(values1)  # [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2]
print(values2)  # [4, 3, 1, 5, 11, 1, 4]
```

Comment: Thank you azro, this is exactly what I want.

Comment: @MD You may think about [accepting an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) so ;)

Answer (score 5):

You can use `sum()` + `dict.get` with default value `0`:

```py
values1 = sum(d.get("increasing", 0) for d in list_of_dicts)
values2 = sum(d.get("decreasing", 0) for d in list_of_dicts)

print("Increasing:", values1)
print("Decreasing:", values2)
```

Prints:

```
Increasing: 29
Decreasing: 9
```

---

EDIT: To get values:

```py
values1, values2 = [], []
for d in list_of_dicts:
    if "increasing" in d:
        values1.append(d["increasing"])
    elif "decreasing" in d:
        values2.append(d["decreasing"])

print("Increasing:", values1)
print("Decreasing:", values2)
```

Prints:

```
Increasing: [4, 3, 1, 5, 11, 1, 4]
Decreasing: [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2]
```

Comment: @azro Yep, he clarified that later.

Answer (score 0):

When working with list comprehensions that are having issues, break them down.

First it can be broken down into:

```
values1 = list()
for a_dict in list_of_dicts:
    if a_dict.get('decreasing'):
        values1.append(a_dict.get('decreasing'))

values2 = list()
for a_dict in list_of_dicts:
    if a_dict.get('increasing'):
        values2.append(a_dict.get('increasing'))
```

Then bring them back up into the comprehension.

```
list_of_dicts = [{"decreasing": 1}, {"increasing": 4}, {"decreasing": 1}, {"increasing": 3},{"decreasing": 1},
             {"increasing": 1},{"decreasing": 1}, {"increasing": 5}, {"decreasing": 2}, {"increasing": 11},
             {"decreasing": 1}, {"increasing": 1},{"decreasing": 2}, {"increasing": 4}]

values1 = [a_dict.get('decreasing') for a_dict in list_of_dicts if a_dict.get('decreasing')]
values2 = [a_dict.get('increasing') for a_dict in list_of_dicts if a_dict.get('increasing')]

values11 = list()
for a_dict in list_of_dicts:
    if a_dict.get('decreasing'):
        values11.append(a_dict.get('decreasing'))

values22 = list()
for a_dict in list_of_dicts:
    if a_dict.get('increasing'):
        values22.append(a_dict.get('increasing'))

print(values1)
print(values2)

print(values1 == values11)
print(values2 == values22)
```

### Results in

```
$ python testing.py
[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2]
[4, 3, 1, 5, 11, 1, 4]
True
True
```

Comment: Thank you JoshV. Your instruction is very clear and helpful.